# How do you deserialize this JSON object into a vb.net object?

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, webforms

I'm using JSon.net to deserialize a json object i'm getting from the GravityForms Web API.

The json that I get back is this...

```
{"status":200,"response":{
                "12":{"id":"12","title":"Test Form","entries":"1"},
                "1":{"id":"1","title":"What's My Home Worth?","entries":"92"}
            }
}
```

My VB.net Object that I'm deserializing into is

```
  Namespace Forms
        Public Class GFForm
            Public Property id As String
            Public Property title As String
            Public Property entries As String
        End Class

        Public Class Response
            <JsonProperty("1")>
            Public Property GFForms() As GFForm
        End Class

        Public Class TopLevel
            Public Property status As Integer
            Public Property response As Response
        End Class
    End Namespace
```

and I am executing the JsonConvert statement like this..

```
            Dim obj As GravityForms.Forms.TopLevel
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GravityForms.Forms.TopLevel)(str)
```

It seems to successfully deserialize the json into my vb object but I am only getting 1 response object.  I should be getting 2 of them right?

The odd thing is that the GFForm that I'm getting is the second one (ID:1), which makes it seem like it's over writing the value of the first object (ID:12).

Any help would be great because I've been messing with this for the better part of 2 days and I'm lost.

Edit:

This was not clear in my question above. I do not know the number of GFForm objects that I get back from the web service.  It could be 2 (like in the example) or  it could be 32 or 45 or whatever.

I'd like to put the GFForm objects in something I can bind to a datagridview

Answer (score 0):

You have two GFForm properties in your response, but one Response object with one property to fill. Maybe you should try using something like that

```
Namespace Forms
    Public Class GFForm
        Public Property id As String
        Public Property title As String
        Public Property entries As String
    End Class

    Public Class Response
        <JsonProperty("1")>
        Public Property GFForms1 As GFForm
        Public Property GFForms12 As GFForm
    End Class

    Public Class TopLevel
        Public Property status As Integer
        Public Property response As Response
    End Class
End Namespace
```

EDIT: If you don't know the number of response properties, try creating a new Response object for each property.

Comment: Thanks for your feed back Panayotis!  That does work, but my problem is that I do not know the number of GFForms that I get back in the Json object.  Could be 2 could be 32.  I'll add that to my question as it was not clear.  Thanks again